# Does D&D Damage math work the same as Normal Math?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage

Noob Here,

Making a Beast Master Ranger for 5e, from the Revised Unearthed Arcana...thing. I have an ape and it says in the monster manual that he has 
 2 attacks both with a 
 Hit: 6(1d6+3) bludgeoning damage.

So math, I assume this means I roll a 1 D6, say I roll a 4, so the equation looks like 6(4+3) so that would equal 42 right?

Now because he's my pal he gets my *+2* prof bonus.

so does that mean I  take that 42+*2*= 44? Or is it then 6(4+3+*2*) which would be 54?

OR!

does the original equation mean I roll a 1d6, 6 times and add 3 to each roll? And then add 2 to that?

Sorry if this seems a really dumb question, but I wanna get this right.

Answer (score 3):

The number outside the parenthesis is the average damage for if the DM is using it as an NPC and chooses to not roll for damage. (Note: 1d6 (average 3.5) + 3 = 6.5, and monsters round damage down to determine the average, which is how we arrive at the 6)

The formula inside is the one for rolling the damage.

Since rangers from the [Ranger Revised UA](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf) add proficiency to damage of their beasts, your ape would hit for (1d6 + 3 + proficiency bonus) damage with either his Fist or Rock attack.

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

They are providing both the average damage, if you don't want to roll, and the die roll, if you do.  An ape's attack does 6 *or* 1d6+3 damage.

From [the section that explains monster stat blocks](http://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/monsters-foes/#Melee_and_Ranged_Attacks):

> **Hit:** Any damage dealt or other effects that occur as a result of an attack hitting a target are described after the “Hit” notation. You have the option of taking average damage or rolling the damage; for this reason, both the average damage and the die expression are presented.

Answer (score 0):

The listing you are reading states Hit:6 (1d6+3). As with all monster manual listings (see pg. 11) that gives the DM two options; take the average damage on a hit "6" or roll for damage (1d6+3).

Your companion isn't going to tearing through doing 40-some points of damage.

Your ape will have a +7 to hit though  (+5 base stat +2 prof bonus). It also gets only one attack per round - see "Why no multiattack?".